# SQL Query complexity and Row count over 10M

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I need to design a PRO LIBRARY DB on Oracle DB 11g.
And I have a problem in MARC table.
It has MARC info about books, DVDs etc.

First off all : [What is MARC ? - Library Of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/marc/umb/um01to06.html)

And the table structre on the picture.

[image: Table Structre]

The point is, every book has a 20 Marc info. And I have 800K books.
It means ; 20 * 800K = 16M records.

I need to create a query using LIKE. And this query's result needs to MARC infos.

Example : Give me books LIKE Book name "GRAVITY" OR Author is "Victor Hugo". 
Note: That was example. I know Victor Hugo doesn't have a book named "Gravity" :) -

Will this query be forced? I can't create a query using column names. -The actual point.-

And the last ; 
I need to create query using 'LIKE' -HOW- How can I get CatalogRecordID 's ( multiple ID) author name LIKE 'value' or book name LIKE 'value'

Comment: Have a look at Oracle Text. It will allow you to index the constituents of titles and authors. The CTXCAT index type will allow you combine free text searches with fixed elements.  [Find out more] (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/toc.htm).

Comment: @APC I will check it.